# org-mode wrongly interprets square brackets as footnote

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to insert the following plain text in `org-mode`:

```
I'll tell you, a[0] contains the number, ...
```

But `org-mode` wrongly interprets `[0]` as a footnote.

It's not code, so I can't use a `SRC` block. How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. use [verbatim markup](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Emphasis-and-monospace): `=a[0]=`
2. use escape character: `a\[0\]`

Comment: I use org-mode to publish html. So both the methods didn't suit for me.   "=" will put "a[0]" in tag <code></code> . And the \ doesn't work.

Comment: @Cheukyin Hmmm... Org-mode now support [Mathjax](http://orgmode.org/manual/Math-formatting-in-HTML-export.html), maybe that can help.

Comment: But I'm not writing math formula, it's just plain text which includes square bracket

Comment: <code></code> works fine on my browser. Well, for your request, the most easy way is to generate html, and then open html file in Emacs and replace <code> to anything you want.

Comment: It's possibly odd that org's html export treats both `~~` (verbatim) and `==` (code) with a `<code/>` element. Perhaps changing the export functionality to not mark up the contents of `~~` would be appropriate? (edit: Info node `(org) Emphasis and monospace` in Emacs 24.3.1 says that the URL in this answer has verbatim and code syntax back to front. I don't know which is correct.)

Comment: Info node is correct. Try customizing `org-emphasis-alist`

Comment: OK, maybe there's no convenient way to do it. I temporarily use `=a[0]`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatly, you cannot customize what is considered a footnote.

**But** you can override the behaviour. If you never use "plain" footnotes like [1], you can adjust two variables:

```
(setq org-footnote-re
      (concat "\\[\\(?:"
          ;; Match inline footnotes.
          (org-re "fn:\\([-_[:word:]]+\\)?:\\|")
          ;; Match other footnotes.
          ;; "\\(?:\\([0-9]+\\)\\]\\)\\|"
          (org-re "\\(fn:[-_[:word:]]+\\)")
          "\\)"))

(setq org-footnote-definition-re
      (org-re "^\\[\\(fn:[-_[:word:]]+\\)\\]"))
```

This should do the trick.

If you want to use footnotes in your org-file, use `[fn:1]` style or other styles at http://orgmode.org/manual/Footnotes.html instead of just `[1]`.